# Data not inserting CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am currently trying to insert information from YouTube into a database for future use. I get no errors thrown when the insert goes and the flash comes back as though the data was inserted successfully. The problem is that only one column of data gets inserted into the table. Here is the code I am working with.

**The view:**

```
<?php foreach ($videos->data->items as $video) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Youtube', array('action' => 'addNews')); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $this->Html->image($video->thumbnail->hqDefault, array('width' => 72, 'height' => 56, 'alt' => 'image')); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Time->niceShort($video->uploaded); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video->category; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video->title; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Text->truncate($video->description, 50); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Number->precision($video->rating, 2); ?></td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('youtube_url', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->id)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('uploaded', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $this->Time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $video->uploaded))); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('updated', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $this->Time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $video->updated))); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('uploader', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->uploader)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('category', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->category)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('title', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->title)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('description', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->description)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('sqDefault', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->thumbnail->sqDefault)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('hqDefault', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->thumbnail->hqDefault)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('default_player', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->player->default)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('mobile_player', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->player->mobile)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('duration', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->duration)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('rating', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->rating)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('like_count', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->likeCount)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('view_count', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->viewCount)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('comment_count', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->commentCount)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('embed', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $video->accessControl->embed)); ?>
            <td><?php echo $video->viewCount; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $video->accessControl->embed; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Add News'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php //echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I figured that maybe there is a better way to display the items and have the values be set although I am new to cake so I am unsure of what I should be looking for in order to make a form with preset unchangeable values other than form->input(type => hidden);

**The Controller:**

```
if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

            //debug($this->request->data);
            if($this->Youtube->save($this->request-data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post was added');
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        }
```

I have checked my naming of the tables etc and they are all correct. Im not sure where the break is happening or how I can get cake to relay any MySQL errors that are occurring. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Stupidity got the best of me on this one... Syntax typo was what was preventing me from being able to save the data here: `if($this->Youtube->save($this->request-data))` which should be `if($this->Youtube->save($this->request->data))`. was missing a `>`... I suppose half the time that is the issue that is hand though... dang typos!

Comment: Since variable names can't contain dashes this typo should have been noted on any editor that applies proper syntax highlighting :)